how do I correctly check that some aggregated results are correct?
My data project is all based on aggregating data and showing aggregate calculations for analysis. The Aggregated calculations can be sliced and diced according to several dimensions.
So far developers are showing me that the final sum matches an agreed total result with a certain range of accuracy.
But when I slice the data on some dimension, the accuracy is not so good.
Is there a data science concept to explain this kind of problem and how should be approached?
I mean technically I could simply ask to match Agg_value(dim1, dim2, ...) against a set of values for each dimension...
How can I frame it from a data science governance point of view?

I think these issues you're facing fall under the domain of data reconciliation and integrity in multi-dimensional aggregation. Commonly referred to as "aggregation reconciliation errors," these occur when discrepancies arise between total aggregates and their sliced results. Such errors often stem from granular data issues, including missing, duplicated, or incorrectly labelled records, which become more pronounced in smaller subsets. Metrics that are not strictly additive, such as averages, ratios, or weighted calculations, can further contribute to inconsistencies. Rounding and truncation errors, as well as numerical precision issues, can accumulate during multi-dimensional operations, affecting the accuracy of results. Additionally, assumptions or errors in computational logic within aggregation algorithms can exacerbate these problems.
To address these challenges from a governance perspective, you should define and enforce accuracy standards. These standards should establish tolerances for both overall aggregates and dimensional slices. For example, an organisation might require that aggregated totals match within $\pm \text{0.1}\%$ and dimensional slices within $\pm \text{0.5}\%$ (actual tolerances should be based on business requirements or acceptable error thresholds, of cours). To ensure compliance, data reconciliation policies should mandate the validation of global aggregates alongside sliced results. Automated pipelines can facilitate these validations at multiple levels, starting from granular datasets to dimensional aggregates. Moreover, documenting potential error sources (such as rounding, missing data, or algorithmic assumptions) helps to enable effective root cause analysis when discrepancies arise.
A robust validation framework helps to ensure consistency across dimensions. Cross-tab validation is a very effective method, confirming that sub-aggregates across dimensions sum to their parent totals, where appropriate. Synthetic benchmarks, created from controlled datasets with known values, can further test aggregation logic systematically. Discrepancies can be visualised as percentages (for example on dashboards) to highlight problem areas and enhance transparency. Data lineage tracking also plays a vital role, documenting the steps in the aggregation process and ensuring traceability.
Building on this validation framework, a technical implementation should include systematic cross-tab testing to verify consistency at all levels. Assigning responsibility for validation to designated roles, such as data stewards or QA engineers, ensures accountability and focus. Developing tools that transparently report discrepancies and automatically flag error-prone dimensions adds another layer of reliability. Regular reviews, root cause analysis, and iterative refinements of the aggregation methodology are essential for maintaining accuracy.
In software development, embedding automated tests into the release process can prevent aggregation inconsistencies from reaching production. These tests should cover both edge cases, such as rare or incomplete combinations of dimensions, and broader reconciliation checks to verify that aggregates align across all slices and dimensions. By enforcing this validation as part of the deployment pipeline, developers can ensure that potential issues are identified and resolved early, fostering greater confidence in the accuracy of the data used for analysis.
By embedding these practices within a strong data governance framework, you can establish confidence in the dependability of data, regardless of how it is sliced. This approach not only resolves the challenges of multi-dimensional aggregation but also builds confidence among stakeholders who depend on the results' accuracy.

Thanks a lot! I was indeed looking for something like that!

This is a super, comprehensive answer. Additionally, keep in mind how accuracy and precision of the data at the point of capture bear. Over-emphasis on precision (e.g. trying to avoid “totals may not agree due to rounding”) can obscure the relative contributions of signal and noise. A lot of real world data can be fuzzy that way, and we manage somehow to live with it through workarounds such as fudge factors, such as an allowance for breakage. Especially be on the lookout, also, for simple random sampling error, also.

@RichardCareaga Thank you for your comment. You made very valid points :)

This happens because of errors like mixing data levels or mistakes in how data is handled.
For me to fix this

i use clear rules for all calculations
check small groups against known values
organize data properly with tables for facts and categories
Add tools to find errors automatically and keep records of every step
Make sure someone is in charge of the data, explain how numbers are
made, and use the same methods for all groups to avoid mistakes.

And make sure thats happened some time cuze you split the data and when you do that i think some of data set unbalance base on target, check that and use heat map for some of the new data sets (slice dataset)
use F1 souce to check and to solve the unbalnce data set you can add some Fake data base on the frequnce orginal dataset
